# Laravel what to do with an illegal request

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, exception, logging

If a client send an illegal request to server what actions should be done in server side? throw exception? log client identity? `redirect()->back()` ? `die()`?

```
 if($request->get('type') == 'refund'){
   // This is an illegal `type` 
   // what is the best to do 
  }
```

Comment: depend on what you want to achieve.

Comment: in fact im not sure what type of logs or info would be beneficial or vital later

Comment: Log the incident and redirect back to page with message `The operation you requested can not be performed because ....`